# Clickable region map in React

Tags: reactjs

I am hoping to use an image of a map that is divided up by regions as a way to click on a region and it takes you to a page of locations within that region. I tried to divide the image up and making the rest transparent but the whole thing is still clickable. Does anyone know a way that I would be able to achieve this?

This is what the whole image of the map looks like

[image]

Comment: Is an image or an SVG?

Comment: You can use an image editing software to set your own paths in an SVG. There are a bunch of tutorials on the internet for it. You use an image of a map and divide it up into the pieces you want with photoshop layers, then export as svg. Then each path should be able to be targeted with js. Let me find you a link

Comment: Ok, so given that image, it should be pretty easy to convert to SVG. The paths should generate on their own. Then you should give each path a class name so you can access it. Here's a quick no-voice video I found of someone working through a simple example.[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-9YQUmTOdI)

Answer (score 16):

You can do this without any SVG or JavaScript just using the [HTML `<map>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map).

Allows you to define clickable regions in the image and associate a link to each.

Comment: 100% agreed on using image maps.

Comment: This IS the defacto solution, solved since HTML 2.0 in 1995.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I left a few comments under your post but I think I can provide a quality answer to close this out.

- Take your image and either move it to photoshop/gimp/etc. and convert it to an svg. This will allow you to create each path (country, county, however you want to break it down) and you can export as svg with the path names as the layer names you gave them.
- You may not be a photoshop expert...Neither am I. I took your image and pasted it into [VectorMagic.com](https://vectormagic.com) and it was a little big but after a minute it had converted it to an svg for me.
- Once you have your SVG it can be placed in the html with the `<svg>` tag.
- You can then give each path a className or id so that you can target it with css. You may have to read up a tiny bit on how to target svg `path`s with css but its pretty easy.
- You can add color change on hover, fade on click, what ever you want to add is possible.
- To make sure I'm answering the question you asked. If the whole image is clickable if its an SVG, you are targeting the `<svg>` when you should be targeting the `<path>` tags that are children of the svg.

Lemme know if I can answer any questions. This is definitely something everyone doing design should at least play around with because its fun and rewarding when you get it to work the way you intend it to.

Comment: Hey thanks for your advice. The image actually started out as an svg so I will have a play around and see if I can get it to work. I will let you know how it goes!

Comment: Hey the SVG works perfectly thankyou so much!

Comment: Excelent approach, that was what I thought!

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar issue and used a js library called raphael.js which uses paths to render a dynamic svg and provide interactivity

I struggled to find any current refs to this but here is a tutorial

https://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/interactive-world-javascript-map

https://cmsdk.com/jquery-plugins/building-an-interactive-map-with-raphael.html

sample I quickly knocked together

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Building an interactive map with Raphael</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/bar8s/pen/abEBWYx